# How to remove all whitespace except for between double quotes, and eliminate text between double slashes

Tags: javascript, string, parsing

I am developing a programming language, and while parsing it in JS I need to remove all white space except for between double quotes and delete double slashes and everything in between.

Example:

```
Str ( myString ) = "Hi, my name is Bob.";//This is a string//
//This is a comment//
Num(myNum) = 32;
```

Would output:

```
Str(myString)="Hi, my name is Bob.";Num(myNum)=32;
```

Thanks!

Comment: What type of JS data structure would you use for this kind of input?

Comment: @ChavaG Later on in the code, I separate it into expressions using semicolons and then create an AST JS Object.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [js Compress](https://jscompress.com/) it's more for minifying code for libraries and such but it may do the trick.

Comment: This would work if I could do it manually, but my code automatically fetches files with Ajax and parses them, non-server-side.